# Looking for a way to host an interactive notebook while hiding code and rendering widgets at startup

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for a way to host a notebook that does the following:

- I want to host a notebook so a user can interact with it (so something like Binder rather than gh-pages)
- I want the notebook to render github widgets on startup, this way the user doesn’t have to run any cells on their end
- I want the notebook to hide all of the code by default. This would be both for aesthetic reasons and so the user isn't distracted by the code.

I was able to render something like this locally with the help of extensions:

[image]

As you can see in the image above the UI is very simple.

I tried to save my widget state locally and push the notebook to github, but it did not seem to save the widget state as I expected. I also could not keep the code cells hidden (I was using the "hide input all" extension).

So I can run the notebook as expected in Binder but it is bloated visually with code. I've looked into jupyter books and it seems like overkill and a lot of extra work for what I'm trying to do here. I've used flask for something like this in the past but again that seems like a lot of extra work for something that I've got working locally already.

So I'd either like to figure out if theres a way to get this working interactively on Binder in the way I described (widget state saved, no visual code) or find another way to do this.

Comment: Not really a solution but I ended up just going with Shiny for python since I had used it in the past with R and it was more lightweight than Flask and Jupyter Books and easy to deploy on shinyapps.io